# Java separate methods and final variables

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, compilation, final

I have a Java class called **Finestrella.java** where I declare two private variables:

```
private File selectedPDF
private String selectedPDFName
```

Inside the main, I have the following code that uses these variables with an ActionListener once a button has been clicked:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Select PDF File");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Desktop");
                fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Select a PDF Document", "pdf");
                fc.setFileFilter(filter);
                fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    selectedPDF = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    selectedPDFName = selectedPDF.getName();
                } else {
                    // Executed when no file selected
                }
            }
        });
```

Since this is only part of the total code I thought about putting it all inside of another class called **Functions.java**

```
static public void setPDF (JFrame myFrame, File selectedPDF, String selectedPDFName) {
    // the code I wrote before
}
```

And calling it in Finestrella.java:

```
Functions.setPDF(myFrame, selectedPDF, selectedPDFName);
```

Of course, I get an error because it says that selectedPDF and selectedPDFName must be declared **final**. The problem is, the variables are created inside **Finestrella.java**, but my method is in **Functions.java**. Also, I need these two variables for a later use within other methods that will be called in Finestrella.java, but that actually are in the other class.

What I tried to do:

- Declaring the arguments of setPDF as final,
- Declaring the variables as final in Finestrella.java

But I had no luck. I understood what final variables are but, at this point, I think there is definely something wrong with the structure of my program. What I wanted to achieve is having a clean main() method with just the essential functions call located in another class.

Comment: What happens when you declare arguments of `setPDF` as final?

Comment: I keep getting: The final local variable selectedPDF cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: One thing you must understand is that assigning to a method's parameter will not pass the newly assigned value back to the caller. Java is call-by-value, not call-by-reference. You can change the contents of an object that was passed in a parameter if it's not immutable, but you can't assign a new object to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you should extract your inner class and get the fields from the new class; the only reason you get that error is because it **must** be `final` to access the field in the inner class. Something like,

```
static class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    private File selectedPDF;
    private String selectedPDFName;

    public File getSelectedPDF() {
        return selectedPDF;
    }

    public String getSelectedName() {
        return selectedPDFName;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home")
                + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Desktop");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "Select a PDF Document", "pdf");
        fc.setFileFilter(filter);
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selectedPDF = fc.getSelectedFile();
            selectedPDFName = selectedPDF.getName();
        } else {
            // Executed when no file selected
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Select PDF File");
MyListener my = new MyListener();
btnNewButton.addActionListener(my);
```

Comment: Can I just implement ActionListener in my existing Functions class? If so, there are going to be other methods inside of this utility class with other actionPerformed() to implement.. how can I do it?

Comment: @wiredmark Maybe. You didn't post `Functions` so I can't say. An `ActionListener` only has that one method (I added the getter(s) so you can get the values after the action has been performed).

Comment: Let's say I want to implement a function called setImage() that basically does the same things as setPDF(), by creating a button with an ActionListener. Would it be possible, and correct, implement it in the same Functions class?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write a method that returns a `File`:

```
public static File setPDF (JFrame myFrame) {
    ...
    return fc.getSelectedFile();
}
```

and use it as shown:

```
selectedPDF = setPDF(...);
selectedPDFName = selectedPDF.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new class by implementing ActionListener. In this way, you can have your own class for working on Action items.

```
public class MyActionItem implements ActionListener {

    private File selectedPDF
    private String selectedPDFName

    // Usual defs
    public void setPDF(JFrame myFrame, File selectedPDF, String selectedPDFName){
    // Your working code
}

...
...
...

}
```

I have not used static methods here, but it is okay to use static method as your class design doesn't require you to instantiate the action class to use the setter method.

In Large and modular Swing apps, using your own action items rather than lambdas (i.e. inner classes) is a good way to segregate behavoiours and also easier for readability and debugging. Hope this makes sense (and also answers your question).